# @Pattern , JSR303 bean validation : regex check max 5 words and not blank

Tags: java, regex, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I use JSR303 bean validation annotations in my spring-mvc managed bean to validate text input.
I need to check

- if a string contains max 5 words (Here a word is an alphabetic or alphanumeric string)
  and this string can't be blank (one space)

I try with this : ( just to match 5 words)

```
@Pattern(message="max 5 words please" , regexp="^[a-zA-Z+#\-.0-9]{1,5}(\s[a-zA-Z+#\-.0-9]{1,5}){0,4}$")
String keywords;
```

but my Eclipse IDE says  : 
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this shorter version if you want.

```
regexp="^(\\b[a-zA-Z\\d+#.-]+\\b(?:\\s+|$)){0,5}$")
```

Should work.

Btw in your regex you say :

Match one to five chars (word of max 5 chars?), (followed by space, followed by zero to four chars. ) zero or four times. Is this what you want? :)

Answer (score 3):

Use double backslashes (\), to escape the special character backslash.